# Fiddler Extension

Tags: .net, frameworks, fiddler

I'm writing an extension to Fiddler Classic (which forces me to use .Net Framework instead of Core) in C# and needs to make a REST API call using HttpClient in one of the methods within the extension class. I wanted to minimize issues so I made a local call first to an MVC test application I wrote and can see that it is getting through:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44331/weatherforecast");

var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

However, the response doesn't reach the third line and seems to hang

question 1) What could I be missing?
question 2) Is there a right way of using HttpClient within a Fiddler C# extension? I couldn't find much documentation

Comment: The example in the HttpClient documentation also uses `await` on `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0#examples

Comment: thanks, I wrote this manually fixing now

Comment: sorry, I think .Result doesn't require await